# Average probability of $0$ determinant for integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I'm new here. I am not a student of math, so my analytical skills are quite weak. However, I have been thinking about this question for a while:

**Given a $3x3$ matrix whose elements are selected uniformly at random on some range {$-n,...,n$}, how does P(det=/=0) behave as n tends to ∞?**

I asked someone much smarter than me, and he advised me to simulate it using the simple case of $0-1$ matrices first and expand the range of possible values from there, to see if the sequence seemed to converge. So, I ran a very shoddily-coded simulation in C++ that generated $10,000,000$ matrices with (pseudo) random integer elements from each range of values between $[-1:1]$ and $[-500:500]$, and found the average probability at each range that the determinant was $0$. Initially, this seemed to monotonically decrease, but after halfway through (a several-hour simulation, mind you, as it was not well-optimized) I could see the values bouncing up and down. When the simulation ended, I plotted the results in Google Sheets and received the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWxGA.png

As I said, I have little to no skills in numerical analysis of any kind. But can anybody explain why we see such behaviour that initially looks like two lines, and then devolves into ostensible chaos?

Some further thoughts: Is the chaos at the end because the $10,000,000$ trials for each range become insufficient for estimating probabilities on the scale of $1e-7$? Could the chaos be attributed to noise in the random number generation I used (it was just srand() and rand())?

Any thoughts would be appreciated. Maybe somebody will find this as interesting as I do! If possible, tag suggestions for this post that would also be appreciated. The person I asked said something about measure theory, but I don't know enough about it to confirm whether this problem belongs there or not.

(Also, I can provide the .csv file to anyone who wants it. I just don't want to clog up the forums with files).

Edit: After running for quite some time, here are the results of my final, correct (hopefully) simulation. I couldn't get nearly to 500 ranges overnight, and by the end the individual ranges were taking a few minutes each, but there are no double lines this time, and no chaos. Thanks to those who helped!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8lHl.png

Comment: Well, to begin with, there is no uniform distribution over the integers, so that will make answering the general question hard.

Comment: I see. So does that imply that the sort of spirit of the question is moot? Or is it just a personal lack of understanding of mathematical terminology that creates the issue? Is there a distribution over the integers that would satisfy the sort of "even" randomness I wanted to achieve?

Comment: To clarify Misha's point, Saying that "each entry is uniformly random over $\{-x,\ldots,x\}$" is perfectly fine. Saying that "each entry is uniformly random over the set of all integers" doesn't make sense since there is no uniform distribution over the integers.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. Would it make sense to say, maybe, that I want a discrete uniform distribution over {-n, . . ., n} where n is arbitrarily large? Or is that just me grasping at straws?

Comment: You could reasonably say that "Each entry of a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ is chosen uniformly at random from $\{-n,\ldots,n\}$" and then ask either "How does $P(\det A \neq 0)$ behave as $n \to \infty$?" i.e. looking for an asymptotic result.

Comment: Can do. I'll edit the original question, then. Thanks!

Comment: Does one of the two curves correspond to even values of $x$ and the other to odd values of $x$? Also, regarding the "chaos" at the end, if you have an event whose true probability is $p$, then the standard deviation in estimating the probability $p$ from $n$ trials is $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$. So if $p$ is about $\sim 1/n$, then the standard deviation will also be about $\sim 1/n$, and so, it is hard to estimate the probability precisely from that many trials.

Comment: I think @JimmyK4542 hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Just at a glance, it does seem like the values are on the higher line for odd-numbered range values, and on the lower line for even-numbered range values. I also appreciate the insight about the number of trials. That gives me hope that the question has an answer, instead of just being random. Unfortunately, I don't think I can run the simulation with, say 1,000,000,000 trials each, as that might take days. But perhaps a better coder than I might be able to do something like that

Comment: @DylanS I know that $10^9$ trials per range is unrealistic. But what do you get if you select a parser set of ranges, and run longer sims on those? Make, say, $100$ zero determinants the terminating condition for the loop.

Comment: Oh, I see. Based on your response below, I think this would be well-worth doing. It is nearly midnight here now, so I don't have the time I imagine that might take, but I'll edit my simulation code tomorrow and I'll see if I get more reasonable results. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I just ran $10^7$ trials for each of the value bounds of $x = 1,\ldots,50$. I did not see two separate curves for even/odd values of $x$. I'm not sure if I made a mistake here. But I did see that the empirical value of $P(\det A = 0)$ vs $n$ seemed to decay like $n^{-3}$.

Comment: With $100$ zero determinants within a sample the standard deviation would be $\sigma\approx 10$. So a 95 per cent error bar goes from $80$ to $120$ for the "true" frequency of zero determinants.

Comment: Dang, if the simulation you ran doesn't give two lines, I presume that my random number generation is probably inaccurate. This may be because I used the modulus function as my range-determiner. It seems that, according to stack overflow, this is a beginner's mistake.

Comment: Okay, I found a more robust function for generating a random number within some range on stack overflow and appropriated it for my purposes. Running the first 50 ranges, the lines seem to have converged, but the values are now quite rough. I assume that is because @Jyrki Lahtonen's suggestion for 200 failures assumes very low probability of success, which is not the case for the beginning 50 ranges. I'll edit my code to run either until 200 failures or until a million iterations, whichever is shorter. Hopefully that is done running by bedtime.

Comment: Sounds familiar :-) Yeah, to get a smooth plot you want error bars much smaller than $\pm20$ per cent!

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively obvious that as the range increases, the probability tends to zero.
After all, at "the continuous limit" zero determinant corresponds to a set of measure zero in any bounded box inside $\Bbb{R}^{3\times3}$. We get the continuouts limit by normalizing the entries to be floats in the range $[-1,1]$. Simply by dividing them with the maximum, a process that does not alter the vanishing of the determinant!

My experience in simulating components of telecommunications systems (where it is essential to estimate very low error probabilities) strongly suggests to me that the "jumping up and down" that you see is due to insufficient number of trials. The rule of thumb when determining the accuracy of a (low) probability estimate based on Bernoulli trials is that to get one significant digit you need 200 failures. This is why you see the dots moving up and down. They are, in a sense, randomly picked within a large error bar. If you redo the sim, I betcha you get different results (unless you initialize the PRNG the same way).

So my suggestion to you is to redo the simulations — not with a fixed number of rounds per range, but for each range you should also let the simulation run until at least a certain minimum number of zero determinants have been found ($200$ gives that one significant digit, but you may run out of patience. I've been there!). So if $p\approx 10^{-6}$ your data is rather inaccurate unless you run at least $200$ million trials!

---

If you do $N$ Bernoulli trials (= the outcome of a single trial is either a failure or a success) of a process with propability of failure $p$, you expect to see $n=Np$ failures. But in a simulation like this you absolutely need to take into account the error bars! That is the standard deviation. Here the accurate formula for the standard deviation of $n$ reads $\sigma=\sqrt{Np(1-p)}$. Because we are looking at a process where $p\approx 10^{-m}$ with $m>2$ we can safely ignore the factor $1-p\approx1$. The 95 percent confidence interval amounts $\pm 2\sigma$. So to get one significant digit (=less than 10 per cent relative error) of $p$ we need $2\sigma /n$ to be less than $1/10$. So $2\sqrt{Np}/(Np)<1/10$ which translates into $Np>200$. That is, $200$ failures.